# DistributionNotFound when importing surprise

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda

While importing 'surprise', I am getting a `DistributionNotFound` error:

> DistributionNotFound: The 'joblib>=0.11' distribution was not found
>   and is required by scikit-surprise

```
from surprise import Reader,r Dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the joblib, it works for me.